# How to resize selected columns of a table to specific size?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote the below to create tables on selected slides. I would like to set the column width of the even columns to 2/3 of the odd ones, however when I try to set the width I cannot find the correct way to do it.
I tried with `Set Columns.Width` giving the table name, but with no success.

```
Sub NavigatorX()
Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oShapeNavigator As Shape
Dim nCounter As Long

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer

Dim EvenCell_W As Single


For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides

    If oSlide.CustomLayout.Name = "Section Header" Then
        nCounter = nCounter + 1
    ElseIf nCounter > 0 Then
        Set oShapeNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddTable(1, 10, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=200, Height:=2)
           oShapeNavigator.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 128, 128)
           oShapeNavigator.Name = "Navigator " & nCounter
                              
        With oShapeNavigator.Table

            For iColumn = 2 To .Columns.Count Step 2
        
                    EvenCell_W = (oShapeNavigator.Width / .Columns.Count) * 2 / 3
                            
                    With .Table.Columns(iColumn)                    
                        Set .Width = EvenCell_W  ' <-- here is where I cannot find a way to properly fit the column size
                    End With
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't use `Set` when assigning values to non-object properties, so try just `.Width = EvenCell_W`

Comment: @Tim yes, now it's working but the size of the even columns is increasingly bigger, while that of odd ones  is constant, why can it be?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified to demo column sizing:

```vb
Sub NavigatorX()
    
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShapeNavigator As Shape
    Dim w, wNew, numCols As Long
    Dim iColumn As Integer, nCounter As Long
    
    Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set oShapeNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddTable(1, 10, Left:=10, Top:=10, _
                                                 Width:=200, Height:=2)
    nCounter = 1 'eg
    With oShapeNavigator
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 128, 128)
        .Name = "Navigator " & nCounter
        w = .Width
        With .Table
            numCols = .Columns.Count
            For iColumn = 1 To numCols
                wNew = w / (numCols / 2) * IIf(iColumn Mod 2 = 0, 2 / 5, 3 / 5)
                .Columns(iColumn).Width = wNew
            Next
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The line that seems the most important is `IIf(iColumn Mod 2 = 0, 2 / 5, 3 / 5)`: I integrated it to the code I wrote meanwhile and it does give a fixed proportion to the table to stick to. So the previous method was giving issues because the calculation, repeated each time has remainder that adds up, while in this way it is done beforehand, correct?

Comment: Sorry I did not really try too hard to figure out your root problem , but it seems like you really need to set the width for every column, not just the even-numbered ones.